# full height in flex-direction:column

Tags: bootstrap-4, flexbox, frontend

I tried to make a CTA box with text and two buttons which are wrapped in .buttons class, and centered at the image. everything is fine when I have a mobile view because the buttons are under the text area. but in desktop view that I have buttons beside the text and over each other, the texts inside buttons are not centered when I use larger font and padding for the text area.

```
[Codepen]([https://codepen.io/iCode18/pen/dBQLeL/][1])
```

I know that I should have a Mobile-First. I know that transforming between devices doesn't look good.

Answer (score 0):

each button has to have:
 `display: flex;  justify-content: center;  align-items: center;` and of course necessary media queries.